# Convergent Series test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

[image]

I wish to show the two series are convergent but I don't know how to do so exactly. For the first one, I tried to use comparison test because the sum is less than one which converges. For the second one, I tried to use ratio test to show r <1 but I have difficulty simplying the fraction. Is that the right approach?

Comment: I guess you are talking about convergence of these two sequences.  So you should not apply convergence tests for series, such as the ratio test.  Maybe your confusion is the difference between "sequence" and "series".

Answer (score 1):

The first is
$$\frac1{n^2}(1+2+\cdots+n)$$
and $1+2+\cdots+n$ is a really well-known sum.

For the second, multiply it by
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}.$$

Comment: Right over n^2 you mean for the first and show overall sum less than 1?

Answer (score 1):

The first: $x_n = \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n+1}{2n}$.

The second: $x_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: What to compare (n+1)/2n with to show it converges?

Comment: You can see that $x_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n} \to \frac{1}{2}$ when $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For part 1:
$$\begin{align*}
x_n &=\frac{1+2+ \cdots +n}{n^2}
\\&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}
\\ &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: oh got it thxxx

Answer (score 0):

For the second sum

$x_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$

$x_n = \frac 1 {\sqrt{\frac 1 n +1}+1}$

I hope this helps